# Unit tests custom module not executed - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom, testing, unit-tests

I have created a file under `\Vendor\Module\Test\Unit\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php`

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Test\Unit\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList;
class Toolbar extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
   public function setUp()
{
    $objectManager = new \Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager($this);
    // we want this to be a real Magento 2 object
    // complete with all it's dependencies
    // so we use the object manager to get it
    $this->block = $objectManager
        ->getObject('Vendor\Module\Test\Unit\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Toolbar');
   }

   public function testgetAvailableOrders()
   { .... }
 }
```

My `phpunit.xml` is

```
 <testsuite name="Magento Unit Tests">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">../../../app/code/Vendor\Module /Test/Unit</directory>
```

Under magento 2 root, i ran

```
vendor/bin/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml app/code/Vendor\Module/Test/Unit/
```

I get "No tests executed"

Comment: Is there really a space in your phpunit.xml at  `Tglssearch /Test`?

Comment: No , there aint any space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well your `phpunit.xml` file specifies a suffix:

```
<directory suffix="Test.php">
```

So **every tests you run must have this suffix** and it doesn't seem like your test does.

To fix that, rename `Tagalys\Tglssearch\Test\Unit\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php` to `Tagalys\Tglssearch\Test\Unit\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\ToolbarTest.php`

And replace:

```
class Toolbar extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
```

With:

```
class ToolbarTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
```

Comment: My line 30 says: \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,

Comment: My actual module works fine in development mode